# OpenGL on a secondary display

Tags: windows, opengl

I have a Windows 7 system, a regular monitor as the primary display (serving as a desktop, etc.), and an additional screen attached to the same graphics card.
I want to write a program that takes control of the secondary display and uses it for fullscreen OpenGL rendering. I tried to enumerate displays with EnumDisplaySettings, pick the secondary display, create a device context associated with the display, set the pixel format on the DC, and create a WGL context associated with it. I can get this far without errors, but then the call to wglMakeCurrent fails for no apparent reason (return value is 0, GetLastError() is 0, and OpenGL does not function.)

The only way I could get it to work is to extend the desktop onto the secondary display (manually, from Windows display settings), create a window and move it onto the secondary display. Which is tolerable but undesirable (I don't want the secondary display to interfere with the desktop. For example, in this setup, I can move the mouse cursor from the desktop into the secondary display.) Is there a way to avoid this?

More generally, in order to get OpenGL to work on a display, do I need (1) to have the display attached to the desktop (or "a" desktop?), and/or (2) to have a window of my own on that display?

P.S. It seems that I might be able to get this to work with a third-party library such as glfw3, but I don't want extra baggage (I don't need 90% of functionality of glfw3) and I'd prefer to get this done directly through native API calls if possible.

Comment: Correct, Windows' Display Control panel needs to have your other monitors set to "Extend desktop to this display" in order to display different content on it rather than duplicating what's on your primary.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the Windows graphics driver model does not allow to use displays independently. You will have to extend the desktop to the second display and create a fullscreen window on it. When it comes to constraining the mouse, the usual way is to hook into the system mouse events and whenever the mouse pointer is moved into the secondary screen remove it back to the primary screen.